# Differents mode of mapping using AutoMapper

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper to mapping my Entity Framework POCO objects and ViewModels.

**Question 1:**

What's difference in mapping using that:

```
Apurador apurador = Mapper.Map<NovoViewModel, Apurador>(novoViewModel);
```

or that:

```
Mapper.Map(novoViewModel, apurador);
```

**Question 2:**

When I had to update a Entity in Entity Framework using AutoMapper I had to do in that way:

```
Apurador apurador = context.Apurador.Find(id);
Mapper.Map(editarViewModel, apurador);
context.SaveChanges();
```

In that way, my entity don't lost the Id property, but in that way below the Id property is lost:

```
Apurador apurador = context.Apurador.Find(id);
apurador = Mapper.Map<EditarViewModel, Apurador>(editarViewModel);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, does the last even compile? you instantiate two classes with the same name!

As for `Apurador apurador = Mapper.Map<EditarViewModel, Apurador>(editarViewModel);`
 what it does is it creates a new instance of `Apurador` with the property values from `editarViewModel`
while `Mapper.Map(editarViewModel, apurador);` maps the property value from editarViewModel to the actual retrieved entity apurador (if I haven't gotten it mixed up).

Comment: then Mapper.Map(editarViewModel, apurador); don't creates a new instance?

Comment: as far as i understand Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(source) returns a new instance of TDestination while Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(source, destination); returns destination.